# GDAL version & QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal

I see that a new patch version of GDAL (2.1.2) was released a couple of days ago (14th Oct). I tried the OsGeo4W advanced installer to see if it is picking it up, but it is still showing the latest version as 2.1.1
Does anyone know if when the next point release (and version) of QGIS is released in a couple of days (21st Oct) if it will definately move over to GDAL 2.1.2?

Version 2.1.2 has fixed an issue with corrupting shapefiles that we are very keen to move to. Alternatively, is there a way to update GDAL version without QGIS?

I can test versions at home, but at work we have very strict IT that does not allow anything 'DEV' or even the LR releases of QGIS (only LTR!).

Comment: Since QGIS is now up to version 3.20 (3.16 LTR) with GDAL 3.3, have voted to close as no longer to likely be a useful question as posed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the qgis-dev mailing list is a better place to ask this question.

At the moment, only gisinternals offers GDAL 2.1.2 for Windows as a zipped file that can be expanded anywhere without admin rights. Inside the SDKshell, you can use all GDAL command line utilities.

---

**Update Nov 2016**

OSGEO4W64 now has GDAL 2.1.2, and the QGIS LTR Version is now 2.14.8.

Using the OSGEO4W64 installer, QGIS LTR is compiled against GDAL 2.1.1, but running on GDAL 2.1.2. I'm not sure if the issue you are waiting for is fixed in that combination.

QGIS 2.18 is out now too, but the Windows standalone version is still compiled against and running on GDAL 2.1.1. I guess the LTR version has the same GDAL.

The QGIS debian build still runs on GDAL 1.11.3

Answer (score 1):

GDAL 2.1.2 is not released yet. Only release candidate is available.
Also GDAL/QGIS latest versions can be found here:

- http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/
- http://nextgis.com/borsch/

Comment: Oh... I saw this - https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.1.2-News?version=4 and got excited thinking it was released. Is there any way of finding out when it will be released (not just as a 'candidate')?

Comment: It'll released soon - I expected this week. Voting to promote RC1 as release just started at gdal dev mailing list.

Comment: There is no release for Linux yet.

Comment: It depends on your repository. On ubuntu - UbuntuGIS or NextGIS  has latest GDAL 2.2.1 version. QGIS official ubuntu ppa can use this GDAL.